# UITextField find best match string in array

Tags: ios, algorithm, nsstring, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

For example I have array with strings:

```
@"demo_1"
@"123"
@"demo_some_text"
@"demo"
@"demo_123"
@"simple_111"
```

In textfield I input text: @"de". The best match in this @"demo". I Have such method:

```
NSString *substring = @"de";
    for(NSString *demo in arrayWithStrings)
                {
                    NSRange substringRange = [demo rangeOfString:substring];
                    if (substringRange.location == 0)
                    {
                        foundString = demo;
                    }
                }
```

But it returns @"demo_123" string.. can you help me with this? I my case string must be @"demo". Thanks.

Comment: How are you calculating the best match? Is it the one with more percent of match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware of two github projects for autocompleting text fields. I don't know what their matching criteria are but they might provide some inspiration: https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField and https://github.com/doat/DOAutocompleteTextField.

Answer (score 0):

It is really depends on how do you want to match.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"demo_1",@"123",@"demo_some_text",@"demo",@"demo_123", @"simple_111", nil];
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSString *substring = @"de";
for(NSString *demo in sorted)
{
    NSRange substringRange = [demo rangeOfString:substring];
    if (substringRange.location == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", demo);
        break;
    }
}
```

I do this way. First you sort your array and do find match.